# How do I turn shared_ptr<void> into another type?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, c++20

I'm trying to build an injection class that allows any other class to be injected under a name, for the purpose of automatically passing said injection class to the injected class's constructor. The reasoning for doing this is because the injection class contains some variables that are needed to set up the injected class that I'd like to have managed.

Currently I have some code like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdout>
#include <typeindex>

class Injector {
private:
    std::map<std::type_index, std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<void>>> instances;

public:
    template<class T, typename... Args>
    void inject(std::string name, Args&&... args) {
        static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T, Args..., Injector*>, "Cannot construct type with given args");
        auto resourcePtr = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)..., this);
        instances[typeid(T)][name] = resourcePtr;
    }

    template<class T>
    T get(std::string name) {
        auto nameToTMap = instances.find(typeid(T));
        if (nameToTMap == instances.end()) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }

        auto mapInstance = nameToTMap->second;
        auto instance = mapInstance.find(name);
        if (instance == mapInstance.end()) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }

        // Here is my problem
        auto typedInstance = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(instance->second);
        if (!typedInstance) {
           return std::nullopt;
        }

        return typedInstance;
    }
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int x, int y, Injector injector) {
       printf("Hello from Foo, %i, %i", x, y);
    }
}

int main() {
    Injector injector;
    
    injector.inject<Foo>("foo", 1, 2); // Prints "Hello from Foo, 1, 2"
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> myFoo = injector.get<Foo>("foo");

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling (clang++) I get the error:

```
error: 'void' is not a class type
    _ET* __p = dynamic_cast<_ET*>(__r.get());
               ^                  ~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::dynamic_pointer_cast<Foo, void>' requested here
                auto typedInstance = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(instance->second);
```

I've tried several different things (like having an `Injectable` class) but nothing works so I'm wondering if something like this even works in C++? I know Casting from `shared_ptr<void>` to `shared_ptr<T>` will always have the correct result because the `void` ptr is stored in a `map` under the key of `T`

If this won't work are there any other ways I can automatically pass a variable to instantiations / function calls in a reliable way?

Comment: It looks like you're passing a pointer to `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, however this template expects a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a plain pointer, as its parameter.

Comment: You're correct, I'm going to update the question now - Unfortunately although the error is a bit different the meaning is the same (cannot cast `void`->`Foo`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.get()` doesn't belong there. `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` applies to a `shared_ptr` directly, not a raw pointer.

Also, you want `std::static_pointer_cast` instead. That's equivalent to `static_cast` being the correct choice if you were to use raw pointers instead of `std::shared_ptr`. `dynamic_cast` casts between pointers to different (sub)objects in a polymorphic class hierarchy. `static_cast` casts from `void*` to any other pointer type without affecting to which object the pointer points (assuming the pointer's address is suitably aligned for `T`).

You are responsible to assure that the `std::shared_ptr<void>` actually points to an object of type `T`. Otherwise the cast with `std::static_pointer_cast<T>` will (with very few exceptions) result in undefined behavior when the resulting pointer is used.

In particular `if (!typedInstance)` doesn't do anything useful in regards to the cast. It can only fail if the original `std::shared_ptr<void>` was already empty to begin with. If the `std::shared_ptr<void>` doesn't point to an object of type `T`, then the result of the cast will still not be (guaranteed to be) a null pointer.

Comment: It worked, tysm! Could you explain to me why `static_cast` should be used? I thought `static_cast` could only be used in cases where the exact type could be determined by the compiler.

Comment: @KyleJohnson "_where the exact type could be determined by the compiler._": I don't know what you mean by that. As I explained in the answer, `static_cast` from a `void*` to any other pointer type changes the type of the pointer without affecting the pointer value (i.e. to which object the pointer points), assuming the alignment of the pointers address is suitable for `T`.

Comment: I meant in cases where the compiler can infer the type based on available information. But thank you, your updates explained it very well - I'm not sure where I got that info but it was very incorrect lol

Comment: @KyleJohnson Also you _can't_ use `static_cast` on a raw pointer in your case. It must be `std::static_pointer_cast` directly on the `std::shared_ptr`. Otherwise you are going to break the shared ownership of `std::shared_ptr`. Just to make sure.